# Async File Operations with Suspend in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, suspend

I'm having a little trouble returning values using Suspend. I keep getting "undefined" (I am able to use the variable "files" from within the function - I just can't return it):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var recursive = require('recursive-readdir');
var suspend = require('suspend');

function foo () {}

foo.prototype.readfiles = suspend(function*() {
    var files = yield recursive('src', suspend.resume());
    return files;
});

foo.prototype.build = function() {
    console.log(this.readfiles()); //undefined 
    return this;
};

new foo()
    .build()
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You're using suspend correctly, but not in conjunction with console.log(), which will fire asynchronously. Console.log() is not a generator function; it will not wait for the result of a yield statement. Instead, you need to explicitly call the console.log() statement after yield has returned a value.

Code below works to log out your files:

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var recursive = require('recursive-readdir');
var suspend = require('suspend');

function foo() {}

foo.prototype.readfiles = suspend(function*() {
  var files = yield recursive('src', suspend.resume());
  console.log(files) // prints out your files
  return files;
});

foo.prototype.build = function() {


  // console.log(this.readfiles()); //undefined 
  // return this;

  return this.readfiles();
};

new foo()
  .build()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Maybe I should just use synchronous versions of the these functions?